# NR==FNR not returning same columns

Tags: awk, grep

I am using awk to parse some filtered data. I am printing whatever matches column 2 in file1 with file2 but when I inverse the two I get different results (expected). BUT when I use 
grep -v file3[containing $2]
I am not seeing the six additional values.

I have tried various iterations of NR==FNR I have found on stackoverflow and they give me the same files with 2816 and 2810 lines but inverse grep doesn't seem to resolve what the six additional values are. From what I can see all the lines are equal to each other despite the 6 additional lines.

```
   awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2];next} ($2) in a 'file2 file1 > temp1
   awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2];next} ($2) in a 'file1 file2 > temp2
```

Line count

```
  wc -l temp1; 2816
  wc -l temp2; 2810
```

wc

```
 166593  999557 6053192 file1 
 17504 105024 658110 file2
```

Comment: I should rephrase the title... I can't find the values that are different using inverse grep.

Comment: syntax mistake, i reran it and returns the same results

Comment: @dmckee It prints lines in the second file that have a matching record in the first file.

Comment: each data entry is a line so wouldn't that mean that there are 6 data points missing? edited in the results from `wc`

Comment: @serious Are there duplicate values in file1?

Comment: @Shawn there aren't, they are each a unique entry, the same is true for file2

Comment: Appolgies. I misunderstood the intended logic.

Comment: Most likely scenario is your `$2` field contains duplicates.  `awk '{c[$2]++} END{for(k in c) if(c[k]>1) print k}' file`

Comment: I will check it for duplicates. I didn't consider this a possibility based on how the data was created.

Comment: Are you *absolutely* sure? It's the simplest explanation for the asymmetric intersection of the two files. Do `wc -l file1` and `sort -u -k 2,2 file1 | wc -l` print the same number?

Comment: AHA @Shawn it appears there are indeed duplicates I didn't see. It looks like the true count is 2807. Feel free to put it down in the answer section.

Comment: AHA @karakfa good idea

Comment: is ...`in a 'file`... a typo for ...`in a' file`... ?